# How to include API routes and web app routes in routes.yaml file?

Tags: php, symfony

I have created API in my Symfony aplication and refactored structure of indexes. In this moment my api controller is in the src/api/foobar/Controller/FooBarController.php
I configured my routes.yaml with controllers key but I would like to know how to include another web app (for example dashboard) in my routes.yaml. My dashboard will be on the src/Controllers/DashboardController.php
Is there any option to do that?

I don't know how to correctly explain what I mean.
For example - I would like to add rules for my API routes and for my Dashboard ruoutes in routes.yaml but not like this:

```
mobile_homepage:
    path:       /
    host:       m.example.com
    controller: App\Controller\MainController::mobileHomepage
```

but something like this (its only my imagine):

```
api_rules:
    controllers:
        resource: ../src/Api/Foobard/Controller/
        type: annotation
        prefix: '/api'
        name_prefix: 'api_'


dashboard_rules:
     controllers:
        resource: ../src/Controllers/
        type: annotation
        prefix: '/dashboard'
        name_prefix: 'dashboard_'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: If all you want to do is prefix a route and a route name, you can achieve that annotating the controller class. 
#[Route('/dashboard')]
class DashboardController {}
All the methods inside the controller will be prefixed by /dashboard